# using png as texture, color it white appears to be much larger than color it black

Tags: rendering, color

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

At first I thought it was just perception of my eyes of the two colors, but the different is too big to be ignore.
How to fix it and what's the cause?

Comment: i just made a little test [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ShS3.jpg and it looks like your are totally right and your eyes work great! ;)

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the effort. And can you find a fix? I fixed it by altering the graphic on the png in other software, but it's a lot of work, hope there is fix in blender.

Comment: i wish i knew how...no...i am also interested in answers as well ;)